# How to set auto update period manually for a Google Spreadsheets published to the web?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheets which is published to the web. By default it updates every five minutes.

How can I set update period manually?

Actually, I want to update it instantly and I have another question regarding publishing to the web:

How can I make this HTML page private?

Answer (score 1):

As to the 2nd part of your question: you cannot make this page private, as Google does not support an authentication mechanism other than a Google account for the whole spreadsheet.

What you can do is embed the page in an iFrame in another page or CMS and use the outside mechanism to enforce access control to the inside iFrame.

Comment: Yes, i've been thinking about that.

Comment: If i ember code of doc to my website, does it mean that i can set update period of a document manually?